# Error: Cannot find module when path contains spaces on Windows in Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs, npm-start

I'm encountering an issue when trying to run an npm script with a path that contains spaces on Windows. The error I'm getting is as follows:

```bash
E:\A B C\ny-project>npm start

> ny-project@0.0.1 start
> nest start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\A'
Require stack:
- internal/preload
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at internalRequire (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:166:19)
    at Module._preloadModules (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1420:5)
    at loadPreloadModules (node:internal/process/pre_execution:705:5)
    at setupUserModules (node:internal/process/pre_execution:170:3)
    at prepareExecution (node:internal/process/pre_execution:132:5)
    at prepareMainThreadExecution (node:internal/process/pre_execution:55:3)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:10:1 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'internal/preload' ]
}

Node.js v20.9.0
```

However, when I change the path to 'E:\ABC\ny-project', the script runs without any issues.

System Information:

OS Version:

- Windows 10
- Node.js Version: v20.9.0
- NPM Version: 10.1.0

Nest CLI Information:

- Nest CLI Version: 10.2.0

Nest Platform Information:

- platform-express version: 10.2.7
- schematics version: 10.0.2
- testing version: 10.2.7
- common version: 10.2.7
- core version: 10.2.7
- cli version: 10.2.0

I suspect the issue is related to how Node.js handles paths with spaces on Windows. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/2358) in `@nestjs/cli@10.2.0`. You can downgrade to `@nestjs/cli@10.1.18` until it is fixed.